# Looking for a really good place to learn some straight Java and 'abstract' Concepts to help with Android! Complete Java beginner :)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really new to programming in general, only a few weeks in, and I've been trying to learn Android on Eclipse. However, I've been finding a lot of the tutorials and coding very difficult to understand and during a post I made on here, it was suggested by a member of this forum, that I learn some basic Java and abstract concepts like models, views, controllers, etc, so I can learn how to implement them and to help me understand Android a little better :) So on that note, I was wondering if it was possible for anybody to suggest a website or youtube channel, or better yet, maybe a torrent containing both video and written annotations, where I could learn some basic Java and all the 'abstract' concepts, in a well annotated fashion :)

Thank's for your time :D

Answer (score 2):

How about 200 [videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8)?

Comment: WOW :) Looks good, I'll for sure have a look at these when I can :D Thank you so much for responding :D But for now it's bed time for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading [`Head First Java`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates.  A little different reading style, but pretty good for beginning/learning and easy to read.

Another place that is invaluable is the [Java Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Really, though, your best bet is to just dive in and write code.  Not necessarily Android code, or the project you want to work on, but rather tutorial code and example code online.  Here are a handful of tutorials which you may find useful:

1. [File basics tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)
2. [Swing GUI tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
3. [Databases with JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)
4. [Collections tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: +1. The Head First series is of very good quality.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input :) I'll definitely check it all out in the morning (I'm from Australia and it's about 2am so I need to sleep) :D If any other sources come up, feel free to post them, I greatly appreciate your time in replying to my post :) Thanks a lot